# Apache Module for Hot Standby Failover Based on Health Check URL

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

Is there a recommended Apache module/config for implementing the following behavior?

- All app traffic goes to primary server `app01` unless the health check fails (`http://app01/load-balancer` does not return `200 OK`)
- Traffic goes to standby server `app02` only when `app01` health check fails
- When `app01` health check succeeds again, all traffic is directed back to `app01`

Is `mod_proxy` able to perform this behavior?

It looks like `mod_proxy_hcheck` is able to check health based on a page but that is designed for load balancing traffic between servers and not for primary and hot standby servers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed using the following vhost configuration:

```
ProxyHCExpr ok200 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[200]/}
ProxyHCTemplate tomcat_health_check hcinterval=5 hcpasses=1 hcfails=3 hcmethod=HEAD hcuri=/load-balancer hcexpr=ok200

<Proxy balancer://tomcat_app_tier>
  BalancerMember https://app01:8443 lbset=0 hctemplate=tomcat_health_check
  BalancerMember https://app02:8443 lbset=1 hctemplate=tomcat_health_check
  ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

# Allows Apache to connect to Tomcat over SSL and ignores cert warning
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

ProxyPass / balancer://tomcat_app_tier/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://tomcat_app_tier/
```